# How to update states from outside the react class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a react class with some initial states.

```
let SubjectList = createReactClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        subjects: ['Maths', 'Science', 'History']
    }
},
```

I have a function to update the `subject` array as follows:

```
addSubject: function(subjectName) {

    if (subjectName !== '') {
        let subList = this.state.subjects;
        subList.push(subjectName);

        this.setState ({
            subjects: subList
        });
    }
},
```

How should I get the access to this function from outside this class? I'm working in electron and I've tried this:

```
ipcRenderer.on('add-new-subject', (event, newSubjectName) => {

    SubjectList.addSubject(newSubjectName);
});
```

But this is not working. I want to update the `subjects` array through this function. Or is there any other way to update that array?

Comment: `SubjectList` is the class, what's the instance? How do you instantiate this class?

Comment: If you want to update a data source from outside the React pipeline, perhaps you should take a look at Redux. It allows you to render affected components per update to the store, and this update may originate even from outside of the React app.

Comment: do you have the addsubject function in a seperate electron window?

Comment: No, it is in the same `SubjectList` class.